# How to remove all character from a string until a range of accepted characters?

Tags: java, string, double

For example, I have a string `"0.01"`. How can I get `"1"`?

I had tried

```
String a = "0.01"
a = a.replaceAll(".", "");
a = a.replaceAll("0", "");
```

but this won't work as the string can be `"0.0105"` and in this case, I want to keep `"105"`

I also tried

```
String a = "0.01"
b = a.substring(s.indexOf("0")+3);
```

this also won't work as the string can be `"0.1"` which I want to keep `"1"`

In short, I want to remove all `0` or `.` until it starts with non-0. The string is actually converted from Double. I can't simply `*100` with the Double as it can be `0.1`

Comment: There are many ways to go about this. You could iterate your string char by char for example, and collect those you do not want to throw away. But note: in the end, your requirements are unclear. What is the rule that says that 0.01 should be 1, but 0.0105 is 105? That is the very first thing for you: you must be able to clearly articulate your requirements...

Comment: @GhostCat I am doing an android app that requires users to enter numbers. For example, if the user enters "4" then it should show $0.04. Then when the user enters the second number "5" it should show $0.45 and continue

Comment: What about `Integer.valueOf(str.replace(".", ""))` or if you want to as String then `Integer.valueOf(str.replace(".", "")).toString()`

Comment: @Spectric Nope..[check this](https://ideone.com/UWz4TR)

Comment: I edited my answer and it will be work.

Comment: The methods `replaceAll` and `replaceFirst` use regex pattern matching and since `.` means “any character” in this syntax , `a = a.replaceAll(".", "");` removes all characters (to be precise, it would only keep line breaks). When utilizing the pattern matching, `a = a.replaceFirst("^[0.]+", "");` will do your intended job, replace a sequence of `'0'` and `'.'` at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
    String a = "0.01";
    String[] b = a.split("\\.");
    a = b[0]+b[1];
    
    int c = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

*You will get 1 as integer. When you want to add something you can add and then return to string like:*

```
    c = c+3;        
    String newa = String.valueOf(c);
    System.out.println(newa);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(testCase.replace(".", "")));
```

Credit to [YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/ycf-l)

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex, `[1-9][0-9]*` which means the first digit as `1-9` and then subsequent digits ([optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)) as `0-9`. Learn more about regex from **[Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)**.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "0.0105";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1-9][0-9]*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            str = matcher.group();
        }

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
105
```